# can a background app listen to what is the current forground app displayed

Tags: android

In an android app, can a background app listen to what is the current forground app displayed ? Or at least check if a specific other app is currently being displayed ?

I have an app with an floating view that displays a button as an overlay.
I want that button to only be visible if a specific app is currently the main app displayed.
How can I detect when that app gets opend and when it is closed (or switch to another app) ?

Comment: Adrien, If i understand correctly you wanted to display a floating button when a particular app is opened correct?

I did a feature something like this sometime back like show a button overlay when the user opens shopping apps so that we can show some offers particular to the app and the product.

If your feature is something like above then you need to ask drawer over other apps permission and then needs to write some code which i will share once you confirm.

Comment: it is similar. So far I have my button working as a floating icon that is displayed on top of everything, witch code that triggers when I click on it.

What I am missing is making it only be shown if a target app is the current one, and hide when it is closed or switch to another.

Comment: Okay. one of the usecases i solved a couple of years back.. let me find that code for you.

Answer (score 0):

@Adrien NGUYEN You need to use accessibility service in android and you can do as below:

Step 1: Create a service

import android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent

```
class MyAccessibilityService : AccessibilityService() {

    override fun onInterrupt() {}

    override fun onAccessibilityEvent(event: AccessibilityEvent?) {}

}
```

Step 2: Under your manifest declare the permissions and the service

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
        android:label="@string/accessibility_service_label">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService" />
      </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Step 3: Setup the accessibility service configuration using metadata tag

```
<service android:name=".MyAccessibilityService">
  ...
  <meta-data
    android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
    android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config" />
</service>
```

this configuration xml is important where you need to add the list of app packages where you wanted to listen. If you need to listen for all the apps opened you can keep it null. Alternatively, you can set up the configuration programmatically from service ( I prefer this way as I can listen for the apps dynamically).

Step 4: xml configuration way

```
<accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:description="@string/accessibility_service_description"
    android:packageNames="com.example.android.apis"
    android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeAllMask"
    android:accessibilityFlags="flagDefault"
    android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackSpoken"
    android:notificationTimeout="100"
    android:canRetrieveWindowContent="true"
    android:settingsActivity="com.example.android.accessibility.ServiceSettingsActivity"
/>
```

Or programmatic way

Listen for the event in your service as below:

```
override fun onServiceConnected() {
    info.apply {
        // Set the type of events that this service wants to listen to. Others
        // won't be passed to this service.
        eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED or AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED

        // If you only want this service to work with specific applications, set their
        // package names here. Otherwise, when the service is activated, it will listen
        // to events from all applications.
        packageNames = arrayOf("com.example.android.myFirstApp", "com.example.android.mySecondApp")

        // Set the type of feedback your service will provide.
        feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_SPOKEN

        // Default services are invoked only if no package-specific ones are present
        // for the type of AccessibilityEvent generated. This service *is*
        // application-specific, so the flag isn't necessary. If this was a
        // general-purpose service, it would be worth considering setting the
        // DEFAULT flag.

        // flags = AccessibilityServiceInfo.DEFAULT;

        notificationTimeout = 100
    }

    this.serviceInfo = info

}
```

And here you go! you can proceed with your business logic like showing a floating bubble button (and its click actions) or any other features.

You can even look for the content of the page as well by using `[AccessibilityEvent][1]`

Do let me know if you need any further info.

Comment: Tried to translate from Kotlin to java but something seems to not be working properly

I went 

`AccessibilityServiceInfo info = this.getServiceInfo();info.eventTypes = TYPES_ALL_MASK;this.setServiceInfo(info);`

If I set 
`info.eventTypes = TYPES_ALL_MASK; // -1`

I am receiving all events properly, so I can do what I want with them.

But if I set
`info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_CLICKED or AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED // 1(0001) or 8(1000) > 9 (1001)`

I stop getting any events at all ?